# Powershell bulk removal of Server tag in aspx page

Tags: 2013, powershell, navigation, migration

I have an issue with sites migrated from 2007. The issue is described [here](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.ca/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-upgrade-site-navigation.html). The fix is to remove this tag from over 100 default.aspx pages

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"/>
```

Does anybody know how to remove this tag using Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

For each page you can do as below

```
$item.file.CheckOut();
$item["Page Content"] = $item["Page Content"].replace("<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId=\"PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb\" runat=\"server\"/>", "");
$item.update();
$item.file.CheckIn("Removed tag");
```